# PHP Thread dispatching request to specific thread

Tags: php, multithreading

I'm trying to do something weird :)
So... I have 1 HTTP request = 1 PHP Process, that PHP process takes the params from the request (which include remote_url) then that PHP does PHP Curl to download that remote url with CURL.

So I'm trying to reuse CURL handle IF the remote_url is same domain, but it's not possible as it's a new PHP process every request,

So I'm thinking... is it possible to do it with threading so that 1 thread is dedicated to 1 domain? So when a new http request comes in, php dispatcher sends it to that thread if active, if not creates it.

I'm not sure if PHP is even capable of doing that?

Thanks!

Comment: There _are_ "asynchronous concurrency" runtimes for PHP (e.g. Amp, React, Swoole), but I would approach this a different way: hand each incoming request off to a queue using something like RabbitMQ or Gearman, and then have "worker" processes which specialise in particular domains.

Comment: I removed the [tag:apache] and [tag:nginx] tags as you don't give any indication that this question is specific to the server(s). If you were looking for a plugin to any of them, this question is off-topic for stackoverflow (as all software-recommendations are).

Comment: @IMSoP But I would need to return a response (modified version of downloaded file) for every request.. so I think it's not something I can put in RabbitMQ and similar technologies.. or can I?